# Method writing pattern

Tags: c#, delegates

I recently noticed the following code which basically defines a class method

```
public Func<string, string> SampleMethod = inputParam =>
{
    return inputParam.ToUpper();
};
```

which is the same as doing it in the old fashioned way

```
public string SampleMethod(string inputParam ) 
{
    return inputParam.ToUpper();
}
```

My question - why would I prefer the first over the second? My eyes are maybe more trained to understand the second style quicker. I find it similar to the difference between SMS lingo and plain old english.

Comment: Based on the answers, it seems the first approach  is helpful if I need to modify the behavior at runtime by re-assigning the delegate member but if I just want to define some class methods there is no added benefit in doing it the first way.

Comment: In an object oriented paradigm, this kind of modification of the behavior should be left as the last resort if polymorphism and method overriding is unsuitable. Overusing this style of programming is not recommended in C#.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Not recommended by whom? I've come across many problems for which this style is a succinct alternative to creating a zillion derived classes. I also don't see why it being C# would make the pattern less (or more) attractive. C# doesn't have to be used in a pure OO way; that's one of its strengths.

Comment: @Isaac: Absolutely. I'm by no means a pure OOer. What I stated in my comment is that *overusing* this style is not a good thing to do. What I mean is, by default, you should consider the second style unless you have a valid reason not to. If it's beneficial for your situation, then you should use it--however, you should really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those two things are **fundamentally different**. The former is a *field* of a delegate type while the latter is really a method. The tiniest difference I can think of is that you can modify the first one dynamically at runtime and assign another method reference to it while the second is fixed.

You shouldn't normally prefer the first over the second if your purpose is to write a simple method for a class in C#.

An example that makes the first extremely fragile:

```
var c = new SomeClass();
c.SampleMethod = inputParam => inputParam.ToLower();
c.DoSomeTaskThatReliesOnSampleMethodReturningAnUpperCaseString();
c.SampleMethod = null;
c.DoSomeTaskThatCallsSampleMethod(); // NullReferenceException
```

This style of programming is common in language like Javascript where an object is fundamentally a dynamic creature built upon a simple dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

They are actually not the same at all. The second is a regular member method, that returns ToUpper on the input string.

The first, on the other hand, is a Func member variable, that happens to point to a delegate, that implements the same functionality. However, as this is a method pointer, you can substitute the delegate with any other delegate of the same type at runtime. I.e. you can completely redefine what it means to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of the second way is it's better from a unit testing perspective - you can test your class and know that the method will correctly return the uppercase string.  With the first method, you can change the method at runtime, so unit testing is much harder.